# (am/are/is) being married

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

To make things simpler I assume that *getting* and *being* in the following sentences have the same meaning. So I will use *being* as less colloquial.

> I am being (getting) married. (passive)

This sentence is in the passive form. What would be the active form? I suppose:

> Something is marrying me. (active)

Sounds to me like the object is in the middle of an action. The bride and groom stand before a priest who is reading the common lines. And the bride thinks: "I am being married."

But people say it long before the wedding:

> I am being married in July. (Active ~ The church is marrying me in July.)
>
> Congratulate me, I'm being married. (But he / she is not in the middle of a marriage.)

Wouldn't it be more accurate to say "I **will be married** in July." or "Congratulate me, I am going to be married." Because the marriage is a kind of a contract (a one shot deal.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have several different uses of *marry* and *married* in play. Some of the meanings deal with an *act* and others with a *status*.

There are two basic uses of *[marry](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/marry_1?q=marry)*, both relating to the act:

> [transitive or intransitive] to become the legally accepted husband or wife of someone in an official or religious ceremony:
>
> [transitive] to perform the ceremony of marriage as a priest or official:

(most of the additional uses you will find in a dictionary, as to acquire something through marriage as in *marry money*, or to find a spouse, as in *marry her daughter to the prince*, derive from the first).

There are two non-overlapping senses of *[married](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/married?q=married)*, the first referring to the status, the second referring to the act:

> having a wife or husband
>
> to begin a legal relationship with someone as their husband or wife

The act of *becoming* a husband or wife (i.e. taking vows, participating in a wedding ceremony, signing legal papers, et al), represented by the first meaning of *marry* and the second meaning of *married*, is usually expressed as *getting married*. Thus, a native speaker would be more likely to say

> I am getting married in July.
>
> I will get married in July.
>
> Congratulate me, I'm getting married.
>
> Congratulate me, I'm going to get married.

You can say

> I am to be married in July.

but like all *I am to V* statements (*I am to be named chief*, *I am to take the pills daily*), it is formal and sounds somewhat stiff.

Usually, to say *being married* in referring to the act is usually to use the second sense of *marry* in the passive voice.

> Parson Brown will marry us on Saturday. → We are being married by Parson Brown on Saturday.

Otherwise, *being married* is often in the first sense of *married*, to be in a state of marriage with someone.

> Being married to someone for 20 years takes patience and sacrifice.