# "I'm marrying with her" or "I'm marrying her"?

Tags: transitivity

Which one of the following is correct?

1. I'm marrying with her.
2. I'm marrying her.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of preposition "with" after the word "marry"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163875/use-of-preposition-with-after-the-word-marry)

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13376/289

Answer (score 1):

"I am marrying" uses "marry" in verb form.  The verb form of "marry" is inherently transitive, requiring a direct object.

"I am marrying X."  X serves as your direct object and completes the transitive thought which would otherwise be incomplete.

If you stated "I am marrying with X", you have deprived the transitive verb of its direct object; hence, you made the thought incomplete.  "With X" is a prepositional phrase which can only serve as an adjective or adverb, but not a noun or pronoun (all direct objects must take noun or pronoun form).

> I am marrying Dina (with her son alongside.)

Answer (score 1):

"I'm marrying her" is correct. A lot of people get confused with this word.
to marry (someone)- this is the general verb. It is the time when people come together as husband and wife. You can say: I'm married to someone.(When the wedding is over) To get married/ or marry someone- this talks about the time two people got married. It makes us think of the wedding.Examples: "I'm getting married to her tonight" or I'm marrying her tonight."

Answer (score 0):

Most people use "I am getting married to her."

Just in case you happen to be a priest, and need to be quite specific as to whether you are overseeing the marriage, or participating in it.

Comment: The priest would be more likely to say that he was marrying both the bride and groom, than just one or the other.

Comment: True, but I have seen the exchange "And how do you know her?"  "Oh, I am marrying her next Tuesday."  "But Father, I have met your wife"...

Comment: I would say either one, myself.

Comment: @BobRodes Really? How many times? ;)

Comment: There was one episode of Vicar of Dibley devoted to this confusion (she thought the fellow had asked her to conduct the ceremony for him and his fiance, whereas he had actually asked the vicar herself to marry him).

Answer (score 0):

Use either "marry" or "get married". However, in everyday English the latter is usually preferred. E.g.,
He married Sue in 1980./Her parents got married 30 years ago.
By the way, you shouldn't use "be married with or get married with". Instead, use "be married to or get married to". E.g.,
Nicole is married to my brother.