# marry; get married

Tags: vocabulary

> [i] Susan married Ed. (RHD)
>   [ii] My sister got married last fall. (COCA)

Is there a passive implication in [ii]? That is, the families and so on arrange and perform the marriage ceremonies for two people, and through all this the two get married. Is this implied in the expression [ii], and not in [i]?

Comment: Related: *[(am/are/is) being married](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13369)*.

Comment: _Susan got married to Ed._ is an alternate construction for [i]. _My sister married last fall._ or _My sister married Joe last fall._ are alternate constructions for [ii]. Nothing is "active" or "passive" here. As pointed out by others, "married" could mean that Susan officiated at a wedding (the names of those _being_ married would have to be given), but that does not appear to be the case in either example.

Comment: This is called a *get*-passive, but your "passive implication" concept is unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most modern countries, a wedding ceremony has two main elements: a couple 'actively' exchange vows (they marry, or one marries the other (your first sentence)), then 'passively' have a pronouncement made to them (and to their families, friends and community) by a representative of the state (they get married (your second sentence)).

Comment: What? You are needlessly complicating the issue. There is nothing in either phrase that denotes active or passive, or two phases of a ceremony.

Comment: Show me a modern country which does not require *both* of those steps. The couple exchanging vows *by themselves* has no legal effect in the absence of a pronouncement by an authorised celebrant, and the celebrant's pronouncement *by itself* has no legal effect (or the legal effect can be annulled) in the absence of consent by the couple.

Comment: Whether anyone actually thinks about 'marrying/marriage' in those terms, that is the legal foundation for it.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no passive implication in [ii]. 'Married' and 'got married' are synonymous here.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but only in the *grammatical* sense of "passive", and even then it's mostly a technicality. There is certainly no implication in [ii] that your sister was not actively involved in planning the wedding, unlike Susan in [i].

Before I go on, let me point out that "to marry [someone]" has two meanings:

1. To become married to [someone].
2. To officiate at [someone]'s marriage, e.g. as a religious official or a civil celebrant.

As SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher's answer says, the literal meaning of "got married" is that you have been the recipient of an action ("married", sense 2). However, sense 2 is falling out of usage, at least in my corner of the world (Australia).`*`

As a result, "to get married" is, in my experience, treated as if it were an active verb. (It may count as a *phrasal verb*.)

---

`*` If I say "Jim married my friends", it clearly means that Jim was the officiant at the wedding, but it would give many people pause; they would need a moment's thought to work out that I'm not talking about polygamy! As a child, I once got very confused reading about the origins of Valentine's Day, when Saint Valentine got in trouble for marrying many Roman soldiers...

Answer (score 1):

Since (modern, Western culture) marriages are always arranged by the two people themselves, there is no implication of passiveness in either [i] or [ii]. To suggest that the families arranged the marriage, you'd have to include quite explicit terms or context. Even...

> We married off my sister last fall.

...would be seen mostly figuratively: the family may have had some part of it, and likely approve of the wedding, but it was not a "passive" thing for either the sister or her new husband: they were adults who actively decided, of their own will, to get married.

If we were speaking of a context and culture where marriages are often arranged, then [ii], or my above sentence, would be implied to be arranged marriages. You could also be quite explicit using the term "arranged marriage", which would work even without context:

> We married off my sister last fall, in an arranged marriage.

This is defined by [Oxford University Press](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/arranged-marriage) as:

> ### arranged marriage
>
> A marriage planned and agreed to by the families or guardians of the bride and groom, who have little or no say in the matter themselves.