# When did you marry? Or get Married ? Why?

Tags: meaning, difference

I saw a lesson in English, said in Past Simple the following examples:

> 1. When did you get married?
> 2. When did you graduate?

Now, Why he said at (1) "get married" NOT "marry" like "graduate" in (2). ??

Comment: Also see *[(am/are/is) being married](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13369)*

Comment: You can say when did you marry Susan? but cannot say when did you marry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this might be one of those English "because that's how we say it" moments.  While you can use the present tense *marry*, that is more focused on the wedding itself.  In conversation it's far more common to say *get married*, which focuses on the person's *marital status*.

Consider the (not-entirely unrelated) example to *get drunk*.  In order to get drunk you certainly have to *drink*, but the act of drinking alcohol is not really the point -- the point is to *become intoxicated*.

In the same way, while marrying is significant event, most will focus less on the ceremony and more on the ongoing condition.

> We **married** in February and now **have been married** for 8 months.

Answer (score 2):

get means, among many other things, to **become**.

To get married is the idiom for become married or enter into matrimony or to be married.

get divorced, get separated, also refer to no longer being married.

Similarly, we say, for **become**: **get rich**, **get well** (after an illness), get stupid,  among other adjectives.